# render data as JSON not working after grails upgrade from 1.3.4 to 2.0.3

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, grails, render

I was using grails 1.3.4 for my project and everything was working fine until I decided to migrate my project to grails 2.0.3.

The render as JSON method was working fine for me for every AJAX call made by me through the gsp page via javascript. But now it is not working.
The code I am using for the call is :

Javascript in my GSP page:

```
var url = "${createLink(controller:'user',action:'someAction')}";
$.get(url,function(data){
   if (data.results != "") {
     alert(data.results);
   }
});
```

Code in my controller:

```
import grails.converters.JSON

....
....

def someAction = {
    def data = [results:"Ajax call working"]
    render data as JSON
}
```

the above code was working perfectly for me in grails 1.3.4 but now I am getting the following error

```
No signature of method: grails.converters.JSON.render() is applicable 
for argument types: (com.xxxx.yyy.UserController$_closure36) 
values: [com.xxxx.yyy.UserController$_closure36@168d2e7]
Possible solutions: render(java.io.Writer), 
render(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse),
every(), find(), find(groovy.lang.Closure), 
every(groovy.lang.Closure).
```

I am really stuck and don't know what to do. Is there anything I am missing.

Also I am using
Groovy Version: 1.8.6 and JVM: 1.6.0_26

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this pattern instead:

```
def someAction = {
    def data = [results:"Ajax call working"]

    render(contentType:'text/json'){
       data
    }
}
```

Comment: Grey: It actually worked :) But I am not sure why the earlier pattern didn't worked. Coz I am using this pattern in my other grails 2.0.3 projects and it is working there. Can please give me some more info on this. BTW thanx a lot.

Comment: I'm actually not sure why one works and the other doesn't - I thought that they were equivalent.

Comment: Grey: What I noticed today that I have two different controllers say A and B. Now in A the render data as JSON is working and in B the pattern u posted is working. The import on both the packages are almost same. Not sure what is wrong:(

Comment: same happened with me but from Filter. "render object as JSON" is working everywhere in my project but in filter it was returning content type text/html. I had to define the content type explicitly as shown above.